# How do I plot multiple Y boxes for each X variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Here's a sample of my data `df`

```
group   score1  score2
a   12  15
a   11  14
a   24  22
b   34  24
b   14  23
b   33  44
c   11  22
c   23  34
c   32  43
...
```

I know how to use ggplot2 to make a boxplot comparing `group` with `score1` and another boxplot comparing `group` with `score2`.

But how do I make one boxplot where X axis is `group`, with boxes for both `score1` and `score2`?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is probably what you're getting at -- first you might want to consider tidying the dataset with `tidyr`, then you can make the plot using a call to `interaction()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- gather(df, score, value, -group)
head(df)
#   group  score value
# 1     a score1    12
# 2     a score1    11
# 3     a score1    24
# 4     b score1    34
# 5     b score1    14
# 6     b score1    33

ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(score, group), y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: Plot 01]

As an alternative, you could pass the new `score` variable to a `color` aesthetic to get something like this:

[image: Plot 02]